# how to pass js value from laravel blade to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

here is my button

```
<a onclick="myFunction()" href="{{ route('test')}}" 
data-toggle="tooltip" title="آزاد سازی موجودی" 
class="datatables__button"><i class="mdi mdi-format-list-bulleted"></i></a>
```

this is my script

```
function myFunction() {
    var person = prompt("چه مقدار موحودی آزاد شود؟", "100$");
    var person1 = prompt("این موجودی را چکار کند؟", "hi");
    var person2 = prompt("علت این درخواست چیست؟", "hi");
   
}
```

and i'm trying to get person  value here

```
Route::get('test', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request  $request) {
   dd($request);
})->name('test');
```

Comment: then what's the problem?

Comment: you can pass the variable in a post form hidden value, in jquery ajax request or even use axios in vue js

Comment: veriables doesnt send to php

Comment: and could you please write an example?

Comment: https://vegibit.com/how-to-set-up-form-submission-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without ajax, you can do like this :

```
<a onclick="myFunction();">Click Here</a>

function myFunction(){
   var person1= "John";
   var person2= "Doe";
   var person3= "Maria";
   window.location.href="/test?person1="+person1+"&person2="+person2+"&person3="+person3;
}
```

It will work if your route URI is set to `/test` & you can get the value as `dd($request->person1);`

Comment: can I bind a value  too?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Just define as var, and concate with the url. I edited and add person3

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it uisng ajax

```
<a  href="" 
data-toggle="tooltip" title="آزاد سازی موجودی" 
class="datatables__button function"><i class="mdi mdi-format-list-bulleted"></i></a>

$('.function').on('click', function () { // perform action 
            var person = prompt("چه مقدار موحودی آزاد شود؟", "100$");
    var person1 = prompt("این موجودی را چکار کند؟", "hi");
    var person2 = prompt("علت این درخواست چیست؟", "hi");
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ route('test') }}',
            data: {'person': person, 'person1': person1, 'person2': person2},
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
});
```